# need finite 'xlim' values error with dlookr package

Tags: r

I'm trying out the dlookr package for EDA and I'm exploring the package with the ames dataset.

I'm getting the following error when I try run the out of the box report:

```
transformation_paged_report(ames)


processing file: transformation_paged_temp.Rmd
  |..........................................................   |  95% (binning)         Quitting from lines 161-162 (transformation_paged_temp.Rmd) 
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning message:
In for (i in ic) value[[i]] <- as.vector(x[, i]) :
  closing unused connection 3 (C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpknk0k6/transformation_paged_temp.Rmd)
```

The odd thing is that I get the same error when trying to run transformation_paged_report on the iris data set

```
transformation_paged_report(iris)


processing file: transformation_paged_temp.Rmd
  |..........................................................   |  95% (binning)         Quitting from lines 161-162 (transformation_paged_temp.Rmd) 
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning message:
In for (handler in handlers) { :
  closing unused connection 3 (C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpknk0k6/transformation_paged_temp.Rmd)
```

Is there something I need to change to make the report work?

Comment: Looks like bug noted on github: https://github.com/choonghyunryu/dlookr/issues/81 and https://github.com/choonghyunryu/dlookr/issues/83. You might try downloading the dev version to see if it's fixed: `devtools::install_github("choonghyunryu/dlookr")`